# Is it possible to allow user to modify React app in a safe way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have an react TODO app. And let's say I want to allow users to modify the app so they can provide their own components to replace some (or any?) stock component for the app.

For example, the app has  component which is responsible for rendering a single todo item.

I want to allow people to upload their own  component to customize the way todo item is rendered.

But obviously I want to make sure the component they provide follow a certain interface expected for a todo item.

Also, I want to limit access the user-provided component has to the rest of the app, so it can't, for example, trash the entire app data store. Most likely I would also like to prevent the component to use xmlhttprequest directly but to access data via provided data interface.

Is this possible to do this via some kind of compile time analysis - when user upload a custom component, it triggers the app build process and check if provided component fits the requirements?

Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: tl;dr: Not as easy as it sounds. Unless you run the component through some sort of sanitize process where you check all possible ways and what the component really does etc. It might be possible though with a lot of effort (as far as I know)

Comment: What's the purpose? The concept sounds similar to services like Stackblitz that have React template to start from. And they don't restrict a user.